# Finding the inverse of A where A is of the form $A = D (I − N)$, where $D$ is diagonal with nonzero entries and $N$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix can be written as $A = D (I − N)$, where $D$ is diagonal
with nonzero entries and $N$ is nilpotent, then $A^{−1} = (I − N)^{−1}D^{−1}$. Use this to find inverse of:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 2 & 4 &\\
    0       & 2 &-2 &\\
    \
    0       & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix} $

I am having trouble finding $D$ and $N$ any help?

Comment: $D$ is $\operatorname{diag}(2, 2, 3)$, $N$ is an upper-triangular matrix with zeroes on the diagonal. Can you find $N$ now?

Comment: how did you get that $D$ is $diag(2,2,3)$?

Comment: From experience. I just know that zero-diagonal upper-triangular matrices are nilpotent. Given the triangular shape of $A$, I simply guessed that one could make $N$ zero-diagonal upper-triangular, which would make $I-N$ upper-triangular with ones on the diagonal, which would mean $D = \operatorname{diag}(2, 2, 3)$.

Comment: That intuition also used the fact that when you multiply two upper-triangular matrices (or an arbitrary matrix with a diagonal one), their diagonals are multiplied "component-wise". So if you multiply a unitriangular matrix by $\operatorname{diag}(x, y, z)$, the resulting matrix will have $x, y, z$ on its main diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $N$ is nilpotent, there is a $r\in \Bbb{N}$ that $N^r=0$. By the fact that
$$
(I-N)(I+N+\cdots +N^{r-1})=I-N^r=I
$$
We conclude 
$$
(I-N)^{-1}=I+N+\cdots +N^{r-1}\tag1
$$
In your example
$$
D=\pmatrix{2 \\ &2 \\ && 3}\quad\text{and }\quad D^{-1}=\pmatrix{1/2 \\ & 1/2 \\ && 1/3}
$$
And
$$
N=\pmatrix{0 & -1 & -2 \\0 & 0 &1 \\0 & 0 & 0}
$$
Note $N^3=0$. Then you can find $(I-N)^{-1}$ by $(1)$.

Comment: thank you, I already knew this though, how does this help in finding $N$ or $D$?

Comment: How did you know that $N^3$ is 0?

Comment: but when I sub all of this in I don't get back $A$? ie when I do all the matrix addition and multplication $D(I-N)\not= A$

Comment: I don't know I just tried it and I got -8 on row 3 column 3, -4 on first row column 2 and 4 on row 2 column 3, but everything else was the same

Comment: I have honestly done it about 5 times now, and I keep getting the same answer! If you try it yourself you'll see!

Comment: assuming that your $D$ is correct, I got: $$
N=\pmatrix{0 & -1 & -2 \\0 & 0 &1 \\0 & 0 & 0}
$$

Comment: It works out since: $(I-N)= \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2 \\0 & 1 &-1 \\0 & 0 & 0}$

and:

$$
D(I-N)=\pmatrix{2 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 2 &0 \\0 & 0 & 3}
\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 2 \\0 & 1 &-1 \\0 & 0 & 1} =A
$$

Comment: @hermes Your $N$ doesn't mork, as Alex correctly pointed out. You may want to fix your answer.